# Declare functions or method in a view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2

Since there is no more code behind in .aspx pages in .NET MVC, It seems impossible to declare a function or method direclty in the .aspx page (the view).

In classic ASP, I could add a script tag with runat="server" to declare a local function.

Each client has its own view. The method in the controller send the right view to the right client.

What I'd like to do is to change some method logic depending of the client. Since this is highly dynamic,I don't want to add a class or a method in the controller then rebuild and upload in production each time we have a new client.

So I thought of adding some logic directly in the view. Is this possible?

Comment: can you show an example? maybe your view model should be more flexible.

Comment: What is the method logic you'd like to change based on the client?

Comment: in razor, this is `@functions` - not sure about aspx, though

Comment: I saw the @functions in razor but I use MVC 2 for the moment. In fact, that's exactly what I want to do... but in MVC 2!

Comment: Maybe you should fix your deployment technique so that it's not so painful to build and upload to production? Otherwise, can you put the parts that differ from one client to the next into a database?

Comment: I can't help but think if you are needing to put that kind of logic in your view, either you should rethink how your doing it, or maybe MVC isn't the right choice as it is build around the principle of keeping views dumb, not to say it is impossible, just not recommended.  Can you give a clearer example of what it is your trying to achieve? This sort of thing (if you do it by the book) should be done in the model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In classic ASP, I could add a script tag with runat="server" to declare a local function.

I guess you mean in classic WebForms, because in classic ASP the `runat="server"` attribute doesn't exist.

So you could do the same in an ASP.NET MVC view using the WebForm view engine:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <script runat="server" type="text/C#">
        public string Foo()
        {
            return "bar";
        }
    </script>

    <div><%= Foo() %></div>

</asp:Content>
```

Now whether this is a good idea and if you should do it is an entirely different topic.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

By the way, you sure the runat="server" doesn't exists? I remember doing that a lot back in the old days.

Comment: is a pity that the function scope is limited to the parent runtat=server block, so the function can't be eventually used in the whole aspx page...